# Translate string in javascript

Tags: javascript, i18n-l10n

There is a string which gets displayed in the mobile menu.

```
var arrowimages = {
down: 'downarrowclass',
right: 'rightarrowclass'
}, $mainNav = $('#navigation'), $mainList  = $mainNav.find('ul').eq(0), optionsList = '<option value="" selected>Navigate...</option>', $submenu = $mainList.find("ul").parent();
```

I want to make this string translatable using t() function. So edited the JS file like this:

```
var arrowimages = {
down: 'downarrowclass',
right: 'rightarrowclass'
}, $mainNav = $('#navigation'), $mainList  = $mainNav.find('ul').eq(0), optionsList = '<option value="" selected>'.t('Navigate...').'</option>', $submenu = $mainList.find("ul").parent();
```

After that the string was available for translation but the menu option was missing from the mobile view. Is there any solution for this? Or am I doing any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about you question, but for translating string in JavaScript you should use `Drupal.t()` function.

So you code should looks like:

```
var arrowimages = {
  down: 'downarrowclass',
  right: 'rightarrowclass'
};
var $mainNav = $('#navigation');
var $mainList = $mainNav.find('ul').eq(0);
var optionsList = '<option value="" selected>' + Drupal.t('Navigate...') + '</option>';
var $submenu = $mainList.find('ul').parent();
```

You can read more here: https://www.drupal.org/node/323109

Answer (score 1):

`t()` is a PHP function. You are looking for `Drupal.t()` which is the equivalent function Drupal makes available for JavaScript.

These are some example of how `Drupal.t()` and `Drupal.formatPlural()` can be used in JavaScript.

```
var comments = Drupal.t('Comments');
var commentsOnType = Drupal.t('Comments to @type posts', {'@type': typeName});
var commentCount = Drupal.formatPlural(count, '1 comment', '@count comments');
var commentCountOnType = Drupal.formatPlural(count, '1 comment on @type posts', '@count comments on @type posts', {'@type': typeName});
```

Notice what reported in [Translating strings in JavaScript](https://www.drupal.org/node/323109):

- For performance reasons, Drupal caches the JavaScript files it has parsed. So, when you add or change strings in a JavaScript file, you have to clear the cache to have Drupal pick up the new strings and make them available for translation.
- Automatic extraction does not work for packed JavaScript files. For this reason, module authors should only include unpacked versions of their JavaScript files. Drupal's JavaScript aggregator will create a packed version from these files anyway.

Just replace `t()` with `Drupal.t()`, and you are done.

```
var arrowimages = {
down: 'downarrowclass',
right: 'rightarrowclass'
};
var $mainNav = $('#navigation');
var $mainList = $mainNav.find('ul').eq(0);
var  optionsList = '<option value="" selected>'+ Drupal.t('Navigate...') + '</option>',
  $submenu = $mainList.find("ul").parent();
```

Your code also contains a syntax error: `.` is not the string concatenation operator, in JavaScript; JavaScript uses `+`, for that purpose.